# Change word color in resource string

Tags: android, string, android-widget

Is there anyway to set the color of a string resource in android? I mean, I know I can use some html tags to change string style (or substrings) but have not found any to change color. I have seen other solutions here at stackoverflow like passing the string to Html.fromHtml(string) before setting the text but I want to do it in the string resource editor. Any possibility?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I know it is not possible. I would use a SpannableString to change the color.

```
    int colorBlue = getResources().getColor(R.color.blue);
    String text = getString(R.string.text);
    SpannableString spannable = new SpannableString(text);
    // here we set the color
    spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(colorBlue), 0, text.length(), 0);
```

Spannable is really nice. You can set thinks like fontseize and stuff there and just attach it to a text view. The advantage is that you can have different colors in one view.

Edit: Ok, if you only want to set the Color the solution mentioned above me is the way to go.

Comment: I see, if this is the way to go I could create my string resources with some "code" in it to know where the substring I want to change the color begins and ends and process it the way you exposed. Thanks.

Comment: `int colorBlue = getResources().getColor(R.color.blue);  .... spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(colorBlue), 0, text.length(), 0);` can be replaced by a single line like this `spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(R.color.blue) ..`

Comment: Also, I would personally use the flag constants declared in the spannable class instead of hard-coding 0 during the call. Makes for more readable and maintainable code. Just something that I would do..

Answer (score 21):

It looks like [this](http://android.joao.jp/2012/03/string-resources-with-font-color.html) method is working:

```
    <string name="some_text">this is <font fgcolor="#ffff0000">red</font></string>
```

Comment: It seems to have stopped working in 4.3 (possibly earlier) -- anybody know what's up?

Comment: [Why it stopped working](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58192), [how it stopped working](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/a8f6d5f0720f400b6f59b0809aaefea83c5f51d4), [a nice workaround / involves code :(](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18839246/253468) and an ugly workaround: for any color above `7fffffff` apply the following: `<font color="#ff6890a5">` put `ff6890a5` into a calculator (optionally convert to decimal first) and flip the sign, then (optionally convert back to hexa) take the last 8 hexadecimal digits and use `<font color="-#00976F5B">`.

Comment: OK, now **THAT** was bloody brilliant. It worked perfectly. Thank you so much and I wish I'd known about this a long time ago.

Comment: Note that anyone using this approach should use the [Resources.getText(id:)](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/res/Resources#gettext) method to get the String and not the [Resources.getString(id:)](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/res/Resources#getstring) method. The former method retains any rich text styling in the String and the latter does not. Also, with the `Resources.getText(id:)` method, you can use the `color` attribute instead of `fgcolor` in the `font` element just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The strings themselves have no color, but you can change the color of the text in the textView they appear in. See the [textview documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html), but there are 2 ways to do it.

XML

```
android:textColor
```

Code

```
setTextColor(int)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think it wasn't well formulated. I refered to change the color of a substring in the resource string. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently made a flexible solution for this problem. It enables me of easily add multiple styles to substrings by using method chaining. It makes use of the SpannableString. When you want to give a certain substring a color, you can use ForegroundColorSpan.

```
public StyledString putColor(String subString, @ColorRes int colorRes){
    if(getStartEnd(subString)){
        int color = ColorUtil.getColor(context, colorRes);
        ForegroundColorSpan foregroundColorSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(color);
        fullStringBuilder.setSpan(foregroundColorSpan, startingIndex, endingIndex, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
    return this;
}
```

For full code see [gist](https://gist.github.com/janvde/0f3a7d90107e6ed8507f1cc74a4fb9b0).

Comment: While a link is great, please [provide context to your link(s)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503), as an *answer* should actually contain an answer. Be aware that being *barely more than a link to an external site* is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).