# Android 4.3+, android:textColorHint doesn't work, hint color is always white

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-4.3-jelly-bean

As the question says: When testing the app on devices running Android 4.3+ (also tested on 4.4), the color of the hints (for EditText) turns white, and no matter what color I set it to, it remains white. Since the EditText's background is white, the hints isn't visible to the naked eye!

I've googled and googled and can't find anyone having the same issue. The app was built using `android:minSdkVersion="8"` and `android:targetSdkVersion="15"`. The EditText looks like this:

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/my_background"
            android:ems="10"
            android:textColorHint="@color/BlueViolet"
            android:hint="@string/my_hint"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:tag="21_0" />
```

At first it was using the default `android:textColorHint` and I thought that maybe Android 4.3+ changed the default to white for some reason. But that doesn't seem to be the case since whatever color I set it to, it's always white.

I'm aware that `fill_parent` is deprecated, but the app was build quite some time ago, but is now unuseable due to hints disappearing. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

EDIT:
The 'error' seem to occur when using a String-resource for hint. This works: `android:hint="Hello world"` while this doesn't `android:hint="@string/my_hint"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems since Android 4.3+ it's no longer possible to make String-resources as follows (not sure if it was ever meant to work this way though):

```
<string name="my_hint"><font size="13" fgcolor="#ffbbbbbb">Hello world</font></string>
```

If you do, they turn out white. So you are stuck with creating the String-resource this way:

```
<string name="my_hint">Hello world</string>
```

And then use the properties on the TextView/EditText to edit the color of the hint. To change the size, it seems it's still possible to do:

```
 <string name="my_hint"><small><small>Hello world</small></small></string>
```

I found this out by reading the comment of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11577658/2422321, by Edward Falk

Answer (score 19):

For who struggles with same problem;

If you used your edittext in

```
android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
```

you should put your

```
android:textColorHint="@color/BlueViolet"
```

in TextInputLayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/white">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@id/etextEmail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_card"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to **Erhan**'s answer or incase you are using the TextInputLayout widget,

I found that using `app:hintTextColor` instead of `android:textColorHint` works best